# Run fsck -y everytime at startup on my main partition Linux

Tags: linux, grub, fsck, grub2

I have an embedded linux system. I use grub2 for the boot loader. I would like to run an fsck -y /dev/sda on /dev/sda every time it boots--even when the system had a power loss and the reboot command was not used. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you considered using a different boot medium like a flash device with jffs2 or ubi (if you could mod the hardware)?

Comment: It is a transcend industrial 44pin flash module. I have the journaling setup and have the write caching turned off. I still get orphaned nodes sometimes though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using a particular distribution?  On Debian based distributions it would be as simple as adjusting `/etc/default/rcS` and set `FSCKFIX` to yes.

If you want to force a full fsck after every boot, then you could simply write create an empty file named `/forcefsck`.  Though I do not suggest you actually do this.

Comment: It is debian based. This will cause it to happen before mounting each time?

Comment: Also, will this pass -y to fsck?

Comment: fsck is ran at every boot already, if the filesystem was unmounted correctly it runs very quickly.  This change simply makes it so that the system will auto-repair anything that can be auto-repaired.  Look at `/etc/init.d/(checkfs.sh|checkroot.sh)` to see the full details.

Comment: thanks, I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: will this clear orphaned nodes and fix datetime errors? fsck -y always does.

Comment: I don't believe fsck is being called each time because the boot screen is still hanging on a corrupted disk that could easily be fixed with fsck /dev/sda1 -y

Comment: Nevermind, this is because I had everything on the same partition.

Answer (score 4):

If there had been a power loss fsck will run anyway since the filesystem will not be marked as "clean". You can use `tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sda` to set the check-interval for ext2/3 to one. IMHO that should force an fsck on every boot.

Comment: +1, this is the correct way to do it.  The system will be forced into a fsck on every restart, but that's pretty much what you're asking for.

Comment: But does this work for non ext2/3/4 filesystems?

Comment: @Nils I will try this, because Zoredache's solution still didn't work.

Comment: Will this perform the check and fix all errors without user interaction?

Comment: Normally not. in most distributions there are possibilities to pass extra options to fsck. For this you have to find the place where to put these. In CentOS/RH5 the script responsible for running fsck at boot is located at /etc/rc.sysinit - there are a number of hooks one could use there - but this is proably dependent on the distribution. My best bet is to do `grep -Iw fsck /etc` to find the script responsible for running fsck. If you found that, please post the script in your question.